# Modify a Specific Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, ruby-on-rails-4, rollback

I have migration (created way back) that i need to change, it's the below:

```
20130923000732_create_questions.rb
```

**I need to change**

```
 t.string to --> t.text
```

how can i achieve this ?

I read along that i can create a new migration renaming the column, but i did not quite understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app is in development yet, just open that migration in edtor, change it to text and run all your migrations again.
Or write a migration that will update that field type.

First in you terminal:

```
rails g migration change_column_type_in_questions
```

Then in your migration file:

```
class ChangeColumnTypeInQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :questions, :body, :text
  end
end
```

Migration will look for table questions and will update column body type without loosing data.

Comment: It seems like it worked with the rename migration File. It does not matter that in the initial create_question migration there is still t.string right ?

Comment: no, but if I have no important data in db I would just change the column type in that migration and would reset the db and build it from zero. Renaming fields with a migration is usefull when you have data that you need to keep it.

Answer (score 15):

If 20130923000732_create_questions.rb migration is your last migration you can rollback with:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Otherwise you can simply down your specific migration with VERSION:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20130923000732
```

After rollback your migration, change your migration file and migrate again.

Comment: It was a migration way back in time. I tried the rake db:migrate:down way but all my later migration's got canceled. Could you explain that step a little bit further ?

Comment: hmm your case is different. creating a new migration will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Run `rails generate migration change_string_to_text_in_questions` then a new migration file will be created, with

```
def change
  end
```

method, now insert, `change_column :table_name, :column_name, :type` now your migration file should look like this,

```
def change
    change_column :table_name, :column_name,:type
end
```

After this, **Save** the Changes and run `db:migrate`

Comment: Will rails know by the name of the migration that i mean the Questions migration ? cause there are a lot .

Comment: You have to specify the table name and column name to change in the migration file, it will be automatically changed for you once you migrate the changes.